# How can I encrypt a cached value before storing in Rails cache (on Heroku)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, memcached

I run a live RoR (Rails 3.21.11) application on Heroku that contains some sensitive (personally-identifiable) information that we'd like to cache out (~80kb of JSON on a per-user basis).

Since we run on Heroku, we obviously trust Heroku with this data.
However, to use `memcached`, we need to use a Heroku addon, such as Memcachier.

The business problem: we are not willing to put this sensitive information on a third-party provider's infrastructure unless it is symmetrically encrypted on the way out.

Of course, I can do this:

```
value = encrypt_this(sensitive_value)
Rails.cache.write('key', value)
```

But we envisiage a future in which ActiveRecord objects, as well as good ol' JSON, will be stored -- so we need *every* bit of data going out to be automatically encrypted, and we don't want to have to write an encryption line into every bit of code that might want to use the cache.

Are there any gems/projects/tools to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't had a chance to use this yet [the attr_encrypted library](https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted) might get you some or all of the way there.